# Where to download a backup of the stack overflow to use for SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Please can someone help me with a link to where to download a .bak copy of the Stack Overflow database that I can restore for training on my newly installed SQL Server 2019 instance?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download from https://archive.org/download/stackexchange.

Brent Ozar also created [some backups](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/) which you can restore directly to your instance.

Comment: thank you so much. My apologies for the delayed response